# Having problem with pseudo-class (hover) when combined with another id selector in CSS

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

When I use :hover pseudo-class with an image element that has only a class. It works just fine and all the properties are executed as specified in css. But only a few properties work on an image which has both class and id. I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.
Here's my code.

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bacon Fansite</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="heading">I Love Bacon</h1>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>
  <img class="baconClass" id="baconID" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/648/648652.png" alt="bacon-img" height="100px" width="100px">
  <img class="pizza" src="https://em-content.zobj.net/thumbs/120/apple/325/pizza_1f355.png" alt="pizza-img" height="100px" width="100px">
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS Code**

```
/*Element Selectors*/

h1 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 200px;
}


img:hover {
    background-color: gold;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}


/*Class Selectors*/

.baconClass {
    background-color: red;
}


.pizza {
    background-color: green;
}

/*Heading Selectors*/

#heading {
    color: green;
}

#baconID {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

As specified, in the above code, the changes in pizza images are working fine, i.e. image size is going up and the background color changes to gold. But in the bacon image, the css is only affecting the size of image on mouse hover and the color remain the same which is aqua.
Now, I could be wrong but I'm guessing it could be because id have more priority than classes or pseudo-classes. And since I have already declared a background color in id, it doesn't let pseudo-class overwrite it.

I'm expecting solution and reason of my problem if my theory about id being superior to classes/pseudo-classes is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, ids have priority on classes, the order is:

1. Inline style: Inline style has highest priority among all.
2. Id Selector: It has second highest priority.
3. Classes, pseudo-classes and attributes: These selectors has lowest priority.

To fix the problem you should change:

```
img:hover {
    background-color: gold;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

into:

```
img:hover, #baconID:hover {
    background-color: gold;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

The same applies to baconClass and baconID

```css
/*Element Selectors*/

h1 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 200px;
}


img:hover, #baconID:hover {
    background-color: gold;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}


/*Class Selectors*/

.baconClass {
    background-color: red;
}


.pizza {
    background-color: green;
}

/*Heading Selectors*/

#heading {
    color: green;
}

#baconID {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bacon Fansite</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="heading">I Love Bacon</h1>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>
  <img class="baconClass" id="baconID" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/648/648652.png" alt="bacon-img" height="100px" width="100px">
  <img class="pizza" src="https://em-content.zobj.net/thumbs/120/apple/325/pizza_1f355.png" alt="pizza-img" height="100px" width="100px">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just to mention a few keywords: Selector weighting algorithm called Specificity (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)